# php preg_replace: replace every occurrence of element (don't group)

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I use this code:

```
preg_replace('/[^A-ÿ\d _]+/', 'NO' , $mystring]
```

To find and replace everything that is not alphanumerical, or a space or an underscore, with ***

Only problem is that, if my input is:

```
tes<<t
```

it outputs:

```
tesNOt
```

and I would like:

```
tesNONOt
```

I would like it replacing EVERY occurrence of the 'wrong' character.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pattern is matching "one or more".

You want to match each one.

```
$mystring='tes<<t';
echo preg_replace('/[^A-ÿ\d _]/', 'NO' , $mystring);
// output: tesNONOt
```

[Demo Link](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9a07c05ee2a83e50615dc49e7f6f950a9fc5272a)

Comment: Thanks! Nice and smooth!